# Hash code consistency using Maps in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, hash, hashmap

I need to create the same hash code consistently given a set of parameters. However, when I am passing a map to Object.hashCode() I get a different hash every time even tho the map is never changing.

```
val map = mapOf(1 to "x", 2 to "y", -1 to "zz"),
val hash = Objects.hash(map)
```

Is there a way to generate the same hash consistently using maps in Koltin?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Note, you can call `hashcode()` directly on your map instead of using the `Objects.hash` function, which is intended for producing hashes that represent groups of objects.

Comment: How are you using this hash code?

Answer (score 1):

The [hashcode contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) only generates the same hashcode during the same run.

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
> execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
> return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
> comparisons on the object is modified. **This integer need not remain
> consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
> of the same application**.

Comment: In practice, the hashcodes for basic standard library classes like Int, String, and HashMap are not going to change from run to run. Theoretically they could change from version to version if the hashcode implementation changed.

Comment: @Tenfour04 true, I agree, in general it should be fine, but my answers was more or less advice not to base one's program on a contract which stipulates that it will do something you don't want it to do.